# What is the value of the function $x^2 + 3$ at $x = 5$? At argument $10$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am guessing its 28, But i do not know where the argument 10 fits in an explanation would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean $x^2 + 3$?

Comment: yes yes, sorry my bad

Answer (score 1):

Since you say that $f(5)=28$, I guess you mean the function $f(x)=x^2+3$ (The title says $x2$, which would rather be interpreted as $2x$).

The argument $10$ gives $f(10)=10^2+3=10\cdot10+3=100+3=103$

Comment: its actually supooseed to be x^2, my bad

Comment: im a liitle confused,is the 5 and 10, 2 different arguments?

Comment: Obviously, they are 2 different arguments. $5$ and $10$ are different from each other. Hence, they are different inputs to the same function.

Comment: thanks saksham , i couldnt figure that one out